# Facebook4j post picture with caption text

Tags: java, facebook4j

I'm new to Facebook4j and I want to sync my blog with Facebook And Twitter? The main idea is, everytime a new post is publised, a picture is simultaneously posted on social media, with an image and a caption (containing a link).

I've used this snippet for Facebook4, but it does not seem to be working. Picture is posted, but no caption is added to it !!

```
Media media = new Media(notificationPicture);
photoUpdate = new PhotoUpdate(media);
photoUpdate.setMessage(notificationCaption);
facebook.postPhoto(media);
```

Could you please tell what's wrong or missing with this snippet ?

Thank you very much.